# How to use conditional formating in flextable by row (not entire columns)

Tags: r, formatting, flextable

Trying to use scales::col_numeric function in flextable to conditionally format only part of a table.

Using flextable's own documentation:

```
library(flextable)

ft_2 <- flextable(head(iris))
colourer <- col_numeric(
  palette = c("wheat", "red"),
  domain = c(0, 7))


bg(ft_2, 
   j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
         "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
   bg = colourer)
```

But if just the first 2 rows should be formatted results in an error.

```
bg(ft_2, 
   i = 1:2,
   j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
         "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
   bg = colourer)
```

**Error in x$data[i, j] <- value :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**

Throwing debug() in colourer shows that x is the entire column not the first 2 rows.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an issue with the `packageVersion('flextable')` as this works fine with  (`0.6.6`) and `packageVersion('scales')` 1.1.1`

```
library(flextable)
ft_2 <- flextable(head(iris))
colourer <- col_numeric(
  palette = c("wheat", "red"),
  domain = c(0, 7))

bg(ft_2, 
    i = 1:2,
    j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
          "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
    bg = colourer)
```

-output

[image]